# Are ER diagrams independent of a DBMS?

Tags: database-design

When modelling a database, does the ER diagram depend on the DBMS used to implement the said ER?

Comment: Are you asking if ER diagrams need to be database specific? If so, it depends who the audience is. You can model at a level which includes primary and foreign keys etc. but which does not include DB-specific features. An architect might design at this level.

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's what I'm asking and thank you for replying. So, with the light of this new information there can be generic(usual) or more DB-specific features to an ER-diagram, but this is not always mandatory. Bottom line, ER-Diagrams are independent of DBM software.

Comment: For a brand new system or software or application, it can be common practice to do an ER diagram based solely on functional needs/wants. Then the DBMS is chosen afterwards based on the best fit to support those needs/wants, other criteria come into play as well (cost, scalability, in-house expertise, etc...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the ER (Entity-Relationship) model was devised in the 1970s, it was specifically intended to be implementation neutral (sometimes called "implementation agnostic").  The relational model, by contrast, was tilted towards a relational design and implementation.

In classical three stage methodology, an ER model is devised to capture the data analysis of the subject matter.  You could implement the database as relational, or OODB, or unstructured, or whatever. This is called the conceptual model.

The next model is a relational model, and captures the logical design.  This is tilted towards a class of Relational DBMS products that includes Oracle, SQL Server, and many others.  This is called the logical model.

The third model is a detailed model of the proposed database, and captures features that are DBMS specific, like indexes, and table spaces.  This is called the physical model.

Very often the logical and physical models are merged together, because the DBMS has already been chosen, and they are both design models.

Answer (score -2):

Each ER diagram will be translated to SQL DDL. So we can translate you question to  SQL DDL dependence from DBMS. In practice if you follow some SQL standard like SQL92 you are relatively undependable. If you use concrete RDBMS extensions for SQL standard you are dependable. It's the point.